# How to know the percentage of certain things through R?

Tags: r

To make it simple:

```
         fg=c(1,8,3,6,4,8,7,9)
```

I would like to know how much values bigger than `7` are there in `fg` represented as a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum(fg>7) / length(fg) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> 100 * mean(fg > 7)
[1] 37.5
```